# Error Cannot find Symbol Main(); Line 20 Symbol: Method Main() Location class Main 1 error

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main extends Frame 
{
 Label SourceLabelL  = new Label("source");
 Label SourceLabel   = new Label("");
 Label TargetLabel   = new Label("");
     Label FileNameLabel = new Label("File Name: ");
 Button TargeButton  = new Button("Target");
     Button OKButton     = new Button("OK   ");
 GridBagLayout gbl;
 GridBagConstraints c;
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Main m = new Main();
}
Main()
 {
     gbl = new GridBagLayout();
     c = new GridBagConstraints();
    int colwidth[]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    int colheight[]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};  // theres 18
    double colweightb[]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    gbl.SetLayout(Display);
    gbl.SetBounds(0,0,300,900);
```

Cannot Find Symbol
gbl.SetLayout(Display);
Symbol: variable Display
Location: class Main
I'm not sure what to do here. 
any help would surely be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to create a instance of class Main then the syntax should be :

```
 Main m = new Main();
```

Main() is the constructor of class Main

Comment: Hey that seemed to fix my problem. I'll mark your answer as correct when the time expires. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Try to find the difference between a normal function and a constructor..it will be of help !!

Comment: Ya i talked to my professor today and he said to make a constructor for the Main and guess what i forgot to do...

Comment: Thats fine..the more you code the more interesting things you will come across

Comment: one more question if possible. I'm trying to use the GridBagLayout named gbl and i want to call gbl.SetLayout(Display); I keep getting errors. any idea? I can open another question if needed

Comment: Cannot find Symbol  
symbol: variable Display
location: class Main
(Display)
 ^

Comment: Do you have a constructor in Main that takes Display variable ?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)
        Main m = new Main();
 Main()
 {
  gbl = new GridBagLayout();
  c = new GridBagConstraints();
  int colwidth[]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
  int colheight[]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; // theres 18
  double colweightb[]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
  gbl.SetLayout(Display);
  gbl.SetBounds(0,0,300,900);